# Context Menus with AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, contextmenu, asyncdisplaykit

I am trying to implement a context menu for a UIImageView, but the issue is this app is not using UITableView, it uses ASTable from AsyncDisplayKit. Has anyone implemented a context menu using that framework? Is there a way to extend UIImageView and create the context menu there?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use UITableView delegate to configure context menu for each cell node. Simply implement `tableView(_:contextMenuConfigurationForRowAt:point:)` on your ASTableNode delegate or add context menu interaction to your view.

```
private func configureContextMenu() {
    guard #available(iOS 13.0, *) else {
        return
    }

    let contextMenu = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
    view.addInteraction(contextMenu)
}
```

Source:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/adding_context_menus_in_your_app
- https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/pull/1795